# Predifine Word Heading style numbering

Tags: microsoft-word

I am trying to create a template with predefined styles for Headings. I came up with a problem where sub numbers are not correct. As you can see below I want to set Heading 3 to be linked to upper one so the structure would be:

```
1   heading
1.1 topic
1.2 topic
2   heading
2.1 topic 
2.2 topic
3   heading
```

Now it is like below and I can't figure out how to make it work correct:

[image]

Answer (score 2):

Ok, I have figured out with this really helpful guide:
https://shaunakelly.com/word/numbering/numbering20072010.html

Basically you should start here:

[image]

Then proceed with these settings:

[image]